# How can I retrieve the app purchase date in order to expire features after a set period of time?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there an easy way to recover the app purchase date?  Or must I save it myself the first time an app is opened?

Comment: Either way, you should be aware that time-limited trial versions are risky if you're looking to be accepted into the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save it yourself the first time the app opens.

The date in the iTunesMetaData.plist changes whenever the user downloads an update and I don't think Apple would let you access file this anyway.